# Why do terminals report their background color as rgb:xxxx/yyyy/zzzz — what format is that?

Tags: terminal, ansi

If I set my terminal background to the color [`#1a2b3c`](https://www.colorhexa.com/1a2b3c) and then query it with `printf '\e]11;?\a'` I get back `]11;rgb:1a74/2b98/3cb6`

What encoding are these supposed values of red `1a74` , green `2b98` , and blue `3cb6`?

If I just take the first two characters of each segment (`1a`74/`2b`98/`3c`b6) then I get back the original color of `1a2b3c` — so what are the `74`, `98`, and `b6` for?

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using and how do you set its background colour?

Answer (score 1):

As [stated in the xterm control sequence reference documentation](https://www.invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Operating-System-Commands), the `OSC 11 ; <spec> BEL` escape sequence to *change* [the] *VT100 text background color* accepts colour specifications supported by the standard [`XParseColor` X11 function](https://man.archlinux.org/man/extra/libx11/XParseColor.3.en)¹, and when `<spec>` is `?`:

> If a "?" is given rather than a name or RGB specification,
> xterm replies with a control sequence of the same form which
> can be used to set the corresponding dynamic color

The `XParseColor(3)` man page tells us:

> An RGB Device specification is identified by the prefix `rgb:` and conforms to the following syntax:
>
> ```
> rgb:<red>/<green>/<blue>
> ```
>
> `<red>`, `<green>`, `<blue>` := `h` | `hh` | `hhh` | `hhhh`
>
> `h` := single hexadecimal digits (case insignificant)
>
> Note that `h` indicates the value scaled in 4 bits, `hh` the value scaled in 8 bits, `hhh` the value scaled in 12 bits, and `hhhh` the value scaled in 16 bits, respectively.
>
> For backward compatibility, an older syntax for RGB Device is supported, but its continued use is not encouraged. The syntax is an initial sharp sign character followed by a numeric specification, in one of the following formats:
>
> `#RGB`    (4 bits each)
> `#RRGGBB`     (8 bits each)
> `#RRRGGGBBB`  (12 bits each)
> `#RRRRGGGGBBBB`   (16 bits each)
>
> The `R`, `G`, and `B` represent single hexadecimal digits. When fewer than 16 bits each are specified, they represent the most significant bits of the value (unlike the `rgb:` syntax, in which values are scaled). For example, the string `#3a7` is the same as `#3000a0007000`.

So you do get `<ESC>]11;rgb:1a74/2b98/3cb6<BEL>` and that means a colour where:

- the red intensity is 0x1a74 out of 0xffff in hexadecimal
- the green intensity is 0x2b98 out of 0xffff in hexadecimal
- the blue intensity is 0x3cb6 out of 0xffff in hexadecimal

That would be `#1a2b3c` scaled to 16 bits per primary colour, though I don't know how that scaling is done on your terminal.

On Debian and in `xterm`, `konsole` or `vte`-based terminals such as `gnome-terminal`, I get `$'\e]11;rgb:1a1a/2b2b/3c3c\a'` where 0x1a1a is 0x1a * 0xffff / 0xff but that still seems to contradict that text above that suggests that `#1a2b3c` should be the same as `#1a002b003c00` and I'd assume `rgb:1a00/2b00/3c00`, though would also mean `#ffffff` is not the brightest white.

In rxvt, I get `$'\e]11;rgb:1a00/2b00/3c00\a'` (and `$'\e]11;rgb:1a1a/2b2b/3c3c\a'` when sending `$'\e]11;rgb:1a/2b/3c\a'` which is consistent with the `XParseColor` man page above).

In kitty, I get `$'\e]11;rgb:1a1a/2b2b/3c3c\e\\'` (`ESC \`  (aka [`ST`](https://www.invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-C1-_8-Bit_-Control-Characters)) delimiter instead of BEL, but otherwise same as in xterm and co).

If I run `ltrace -e XParseColor "$terminal" -bg '#1a2b3c'`, after adding:

```
typedef XColor = struct(ulong, hex(ushort), hex(ushort), hex(ushort), hex(char), hex(char));
int XParseColor(addr, int, string, +XColor*);
```

to `~/.ltrace.conf`, whether it's `rxvt` or `xterm`, I see:

```
xterm->XParseColor(0x55df687228f0, 57, "#1a2b3c", { 0, 0x1a00, 0x2b00, 0x3c00, 0x7, 0 })          = 1
```

And for `ltrace -e XParseColor "$terminal" -bg rgb:1a/2b/3c`, I see:

```
xterm->XParseColor(0x557da7d8b8f0, 57, "rgb:1a/2b/3c", { 0, 0x1a1a, 0x2b2b, 0x3c3c, 0x7, 0 })     = 1
```

Which would seem to suggest `rxvt` is the only correct one, though in practice that likely won't make any difference as most display devices support only 8 bits per primary colour.

---

<sup>¹ here with a link to the man page in Arch Linux as the man page rendering at [the one at x.org](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man3/XQueryColor.3.xhtml) is currently broken. Check `man XParseColor` or `man XQueryColor` on your system.</sup>

Comment: I _guess_ it's a mixture of `XParseColor` and common sense. :) `#3a7` standing for `#3000a0007000` makes no sense to me, `#3a7` being a shorthand notation of `#3333aaaa7777` sounds much better to me and is the widespread practice across various kinds of software I've seen.

Comment: @egmont, yet, when you do `xterm -bg '#3a7'` you do get the same colour as `xterm -bg 'rgb:3000/a000/7000'`, xterm "incorrectly" reports `rgb:3030/a0a0/7070` (in practice won't make a difference though) upon that OSC  sequence, but in any case, you certainly don't get `rgb:/3333/aaaa/7777`, at least not on Debian or Ubuntu. That is XParseColor works as documented, where #3a7 is the same as #3000a0007000, but xterm doesn't. `rxvt -bg '#3a7'` correctly reports `rgb:3000/a000/7000` which *is* the background color that is used (which will look the same as rgb:3030/a0a0/7070, not rgb:3333/aaaa/7777